# EXTJS--treestore getCount() method returning undefined, any alternate methods to check if store has already loaded?

Tags: extjs

I have a card layout and on card "activate" event I load the store. To keep the store from loading every time that card is activated I check to see if getCount == 0 and if true, I load the store:

```
handleActivateGrid: function(){

    if(this.myTreeGrid().getStore().getCount() == 0){
      this.myTreeGrid().getStore().load();
    }
```

I'm using this same approach elsewhere in my code and it works perfectly fine, the only difference is in this case its a Ext.data.TreeStore.

I debugged and getCount() was undefined, even AFTER the store had loaded.

Is there another approach or method I could use to implement the above?

Thanks

EDIT: just checked the docs, getCount() is not a method that exists for Ext.data.TreeStore, so that explains that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [TreeStore](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore) consists of a single root node, with child nodes.

To see if there are nodes under the root node, you can use the following

```
myTreeGrid().getStore().getRootNode().childNodes.length > 0
```

See http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-property-childNodes

A more correct approach (since a load may not load any child nodes in theory) is to hookup a [load event](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-method-load) to the store, when it's initially created. From the load handler, you can set your `isLoaded` flag wherever it's convenient for your code.

Something like http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?91923-How-to-check-datastore-is-loaded/page2

```
var storeLoaded = false;
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'get-nodes.php'
    },
    root: {text: 'Ext JS',id: 'src', expanded: true},
    listeners: {
       load: function() {
          storeLoaded = true;
       }
    }
 });

 var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    store: store,
    renderTo: 'tree-div',
    height: 300,
    width: 250,
    title: 'Files'
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this code .

```
myTreeGrid().getStore().getRootNode().getChildAt(0) == undefined
```